# Функция mail(): трудности с кодировкой

Tags: email, php, кириллица, utf-8, кодировка

Всем доброго времени!  
Когда все было в windows-1251, все работало нормально. Иероглифы в письме появились, после того как перевел все на utf-8.
Коды скриптов в utf-8, в html head meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8".
Похожие темы гуглил, ничего пока не помогло. Использовать в поле From латиницу не предлагать, т.к. нужна кириллица.
Когда письмо приходит на почту, то **в общем списке писем, в поле от кого, кириллица отображается корректно**. Когда заходишь **в само письмо, тот же текст в поле от кого**, корректно отображаются только латинские буквы и e-mail отправителя, **кириллица выводится иероглифами**. Жирным выделено то, что смущает, в общем списке все нормально, значит, я отправляю все правильно, но почему в самом письме все меняется?
Также пробовал варианты:

```
'subject' = '=?koi8-r?B?'.base64_encode(convert_cyr_string("Новое сообщение", "w","k")).'?=';  
'subject' = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode(convert_cyr_string("Новое сообщение", "w","k")).'?=';  
'subject' = '=?koi8-r?B?'.base64_encode("Новое сообщение").'?=';  
'subject' = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode("Новое сообщение").'?=';
```

На From никак не повлияло.

Код php:

```
<php

$mail = array(  
'to' => "tomail@site.ru",  
'subject' => "Новое сообщение",  
'message' => "<html><body><p>Текст сообщения</p></body></html>",  
'headers' => "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"."From: Эта кириллица выводится иероглифами <frommail@site.ru>\r\n");  
mail($mail['to'], $mail['subject'], $mail['message'], $mail['headers']);
```

Comment: convert_cyr_string не работает с utf8

Comment: Попробуйте так:    
<?php    
function mail_utf8 ($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from)     {      $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\n" . 'From: Yourname <' . $from . ">\n";    
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header);    
}    
    
mail_utf8('xxx@xxx.xx','Тема','Сообщение','Заголовок');    
?>    
Функция отправляет utf-8, но, конечно, нужно допилить для ваших целей.

Comment: Или еще как вариант, раз у вас вин1251 работало все, то его также и использовать, конвертировать только все данные из утф )) $subject=iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $subject);

Comment: @ananas раз все заработало, оформлю тогда как ответ )

Comment: @Stuf я писал, что __последний комментарий не был ответом__, он лишь натолкнул на ответ.  
subject кодировать нет необходимости.  
__Нужно__ только iconv() применить к header, как в моем комментарии.  
Подкорректируйте ответ, чтобы тот, кто будет использовать, не натыкался на те же грабли.

Comment: Достаточно поставить кодировку файла UTF8 без BOM, а не UTF8. Ну и в htaccess: AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: @ModaL, все так и стоит, в .htaccess: AddDefaultCharset utf-8, а сам файл с кодом сохранен, как раз, в кодировке UTF8 без BOM. __У меня не правильно указан charset?__ Как правильно указать charset=utf-8 без BOM?

Answer (score 7):

Спасибо **Stuf**, последний комментарий натолкнул на ответ.
Подстановки в subject никак не помогли, а вот конвертация только header все решила. Решил следующим образом:

```
<?php
    $mail = array(  
        'to' => "tomail@site.ru",  
        'subject' => "Новое сообщение",  
        'message' => "<html><body><p>Текст сообщения</p></body></html>",  
        'headers' => "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"."From: Эта кириллица выводится иероглифами <frommail@site.ru>\r\n");  

    mail($mail['to'], $mail['subject'], $mail['message'], iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $mail['headers']));
```