# Php скрипт отправки сообщения mail()

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8, utf

Добрый день, можете помочь объяснить, почему после отправки сообщения, сообщение приходит со сломанной кириллицей? Правильно ли написаны заголовки в функции mail()? И как лечить это?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['phone']))
     //if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
     //if "email" is filled out, send email
     {
     //send email

     $email = "myacc@yandex.ru" ;
     $subject = "Новый заказ с сайта" ;
     $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $message = '
                Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'
                Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'
                Отчество: '.$_POST['sername'].'
                E-mail: '.$_POST['email'];
      if(isset($_POST['message']))
        $message .= '
                    Сообщение: 
                    '.$_POST['message'];
                    #$headers = "From: stroirus@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     mail( "$email", "$subject",
     $message, 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n".'From: romardi@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
     header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
     //echo "Message has been sent to $email";
     }
     else
     //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
     {
     $server = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
     echo "<h1>Mail test from $server</h1>
     <form method='post' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>
     Enter Your Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br /><br />
     <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
     </form>";
     }

    ?>
```

Спасибо.

Comment: разделитель для заголовков . "\r\n" .

Comment: Где-то не те кодировки... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361590/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mail-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 0):

1.Вероятно у вас файлы сохранены в разной кодировке.
К примеру источник.php - CP-1251, а принимающий в UTF-8.

Вы открыли ваши файлы в текстовом редакторе.
Пересохраните их в кодировке UTF-8.
В Sublime: Файл-Сохранить в кодировке.

2. В тэге  указать одинаковую кодировку для всех.
   В хэдере вашего шаблона пропишите

```html
<head>
............................
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
............................
</head>
```

3. Это не вместо mail()

   `if(isset($_POST['message']))
               $form_message = iconv("CP-1251", "UTF-8", $_POST['message'] );
               $message .= '
                           Сообщение: 
                           '.$form_message;
           ..................................`

Comment: 1Можно подробнее, какие файлы в разной кодировке? у меня есть отдельный файл: callback.php, на него ссылается form action="callback.php"
2- В какой тег?
3- Это вместо mail() ?

Comment: Я скорректировал ответ.